# Trying to implement jq like on() method

Tags: jquery, open-source

Can anyone point me to the source of the on() method on github?

I have been searching for an hour and it's not turning up.

I even emailed James Padolsey... his source viewer finds it, but the result it returns is not helpful.

I just want to see if there are any pitfalls that the code already solves, which I may not be aware of.

Comment: Sorry to bother, I was looking in the wrong place.

See the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the source has many different locations.  I was looking under src/core, however, it can be found in src/event.js

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js